# How to click the Continue button on website using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webautomation

I am trying to write a code that is able to auto apply on job openings on indeed.com. I have managed to reach the last stage, however, the final click on the application form is giving me a lot of trouble. Please refer the page as below
[image]

Once logged in to my profile, I go to the relevant search page, click on the listing I am interested in and then on the final page (shown above) I am trying to click on the `continue` button using `xpath` as follows:

```
driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apply-button-container"]/div[1]/span[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-action-continue"]')
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="form-action-continue"]"}
```

Having gone through some suggestions on the net I have even tried the following:

```
driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apply-button-container"]/div[1]/span[1]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="form-action-continue"]')))
```

But then this gives me a timeout error

```
TimeoutException: Message:
```

Will appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From it seems, on that form there are multiple `iframe`s, therefore the reason for your errors.

You need to get the first `iframe`, switch to it, get the second `iframe` inside the first one, switch to it and only afterwards you'll be able to get the `continue` button.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    frame_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="Job application form container"')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame_1)
    frame_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="Job application form"]')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame_2)
    continue_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form-action-continue')
    continue_btn.click()
```

Comment: I got stuck again on the next step and have posted another question. Would be grateful if you could help out here as well. Link to the question is here     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553387/how-to-click-the-continue-button-on-a-website-using-selenium-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a similar issue and standard time.sleep() until the form (or continue button) appears helped me. Try it instead of WebDriverWait, maybe it will work.

Comment: Hey! I have already tried that, even with a 60s sleep, but somehow I am still getting the 'Unable to locate element:' error.