# How to click the Continue button within https://in.indeed.com/ website using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to write a code that is able to auto apply on job openings on indeed.com. I have managed to reach the last stage, however, the final click on the application form is giving me a lot of trouble. Please refer the page as below

[image]

Once logged in to my profile, I go to the relevant search page, click on the listing I am interested in and then on the final page (shown above) I am trying to click on the continue button using xpath. For the previous step (also a page on the same form), the form had multiple iframes which I was able to switch successfully. Now for the current page, I am stuck as the click function does not do anything. I have written the following code:

```
driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apply-button-container"]/div[1]/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)
frame_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="Job application form container"')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_1)
frame_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="Job application form"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_2)
continue_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form-action-continue')
continue_btn.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form-action-continue"]').click()
```

I have tried switching the iframes again for this step but nothing happens. Even the .click() function does not do anything.

Will appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Continue</kbd> is within nested `<iframe>` elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.indeed-apply-button-label"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='indeedapply-modal-preload']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Job application form']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#form-action-continue"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='indeed-apply-button-label']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'indeedapply-modal-preload')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Job application form']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='form-action-continue']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: indeed_continue_click]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Hi Debanjan, I am actually stuck again in the next step. Would really appreciate if you could help out again. Link to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554933/how-to-click-the-continue-button-within-a-website-using-selenium-in-python