# How to click the Continue button within a website using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to write a code that is able to auto apply on job openings on indeed.com. I have managed to reach the last stage, however, the final 2 clicks on the application form is giving me a lot of trouble. Please refer to the first page as below

[image]

Once we click on continue on the first page, for the second page I first need to scroll down a bit to reach from here...

[image]

..to here and then finally click on apply.

[image]

I am stuck on the first page, as the click function does not do anything. I have written the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apply-button-container"]/div[1]/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)
frame_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="Job application form container"')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_1)
frame_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="Job application form"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_2)
continue_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#form-action-continue')
continue_btn.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='form-action-continue']"))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="form-action-continue"]').click()
```

I have tried switching the iframes again for this step but nothing happens. Even the .click() function does not do anything.

Will appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This should go through the first click if your values are inputted.

```
driver.get("https://in.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=Delhi&vjk=5c0bd416675cf4e5")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.indeed-apply-button"))).click()
frame_1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[@title="Job application form container"')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_1)
frame_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[@title="Job application form"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_2)
cont="#form-action-continue"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, cont))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks but this just gets me till the first click on continue, whereas, I am already at the third click on continue.

Comment: The last line should get them all through.